# Table Storage Batch Table Results

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Azure Table Storage offers a BatchOperation method. It returns a list of TableResults. From what I've seen, there is never a time where this return value will have mixed failures and successes (as a batch should be). I haven't been able to find documentation that says this is a fact though. If anyone has a handy link to this specific info let me know.

Comment: Did you try to batch operations will some operations that will failed ? I am interested in ^^

Answer (score 1):

TableBatch operation is atomic, so there is no point to continue executing the batch operation after the first failure. There are 2 outcomes for a TableBatchOperation, either all operations succeed and the overall request succeeds or the request returns on the first failed operation, and the changes made by previous operations are rolled back.

The interesting thing here is that, you will get a StorageException if there is a failure in one of the operations in the batch and the index of the failed operation is embedded inside the StorageException object. Then if you want to, you can implement the logic to automatically remove that operation from the batch (and log) and resubmit the TableBatchOperation.

I have implemented a StorageException extension class which extracts the failed operation index and many other useful information from the StorageException object.

Feel free to use it: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureStorageExceptionParser/